# calling a function using nested controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

got struck with nested controllers.The main objective of this code is to make data extracted from .json hyperlink to another file/function.

.html file:

```
<div ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="GetCtrl"  >
<li  ng-controller="ChannelCtrl" ng-repeat="x in Operator">
        <a  href="getChannels({{x.OP_Name}})" > {{ x.OP_Name}} <br/></a>
    </li></div>`
```

app.js:

```
app.controller('GetCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('partials/operator.json')
        .then(function (response) {$scope.Operator = response.data.Operator;});
});
app.service('ChannelList', function () {
    this.getChannels = function(chname) {
        document.write("In Idea");
    }
});
app.controller('ChannelCtrl',function($scope,$http,ChannelList) {
    ChannelList.getChannels();
});
```

.json file:

```
 {
      "Operator" : [
           {"OP_Name":"IDEA"},
           {"OP_Name":"VODAFONE"},
           {"OP_Name":"AIRTEL"},
           {"OP_Name":"BSNL"},
           {"OP_Name":"DOCOMO"},
           {"OP_Name":"AIRCEL"},
           {"OP_Name":"DIALOG"}
      ]
 }
```

The problem that I am facing is only either of the controllers is in action at time.I'm not able to work with both of these controllers as a result i'm having an incomplete output.
I'm able to call the function as well as display content of .json file.But I'm not able to perform both the actions at a time.

Output has to be like:

```
 .Idea
 .Airtel
 .
 .
 .
```

When I click one of these hyperlinks the getchannels() function has to be called.

Comment: Is your code working when we use only a single controller?

Comment: Hello Che, the code is working fine with single controller

Answer (score 0):

To call the controller function, you might need to use ng-click and cannot call the controller function using href.

```
<a href="#" ng-click="getChannels(x.OP_Name)"> {{ x.OP_Name}}</a><br/>
```

[Pls hava a look at this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/t8G8PaqpVQlx3IqFnWVY?p=preview)